# Chrome Extention: I've not specified "host permission" as a premition, yet I need to explain why

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I am about to publish a Google Chrome Extention, and I've run into a problem.

I have to write reasons for `tabs`, `storage`, and `host permission`

**But** in my manifest, I've only asked for *tabs* and *storage*, not *host permission*.

---

**Manifest:**

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "include_globs": [
                "*://*.instagram.*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup" : "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "storage"],
    "icons": {
        "128": "128x128.png",
        "48": "48x48.png",
        "16": "16x16.png"
    }
}
```

**So what does `host permission` mean, since I don't know what to write in the reasoning.**

Comment: Host permissions also include `matches` of `content_scripts`. Remove `include_globs` and replace `"*://*/*"` with `"*://*.instagram.com/*"` and add any other domains explicitly as well.